# iOS Swift Summing up CoreData attribute values

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, xcode7.1beta

```
Setup: Xcode version: 7.1 Beta, 
Firmware: iOS 9,
```

I am trying to access a value from Core Data to get the gross total of product purchased. I have checked a question on the same, but it is in Obj C. CoreData details:

Entity: Cart

Attributes: fName (String), fCost (Integer 16), fQuantity (Integer 16)

Retrieving code is as below:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cart")
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    print("===\(results)")

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Print(results) output is as below:

```
[<Tif.Cart: 0x7f8d19e60d00> (entity: Cart; id: 0xd000000000240000 <x-coredata://5D617B2C-35BC-43B4-BEC1-40AABA96C558/Cart/p9> ; data: {
    fCost = 30;
    fName = "Milk";
    fQuantity = 2;
}), <Tif.Cart: 0x7f8d19e7cd80> (entity: Cart; id: 0xd000000000280000 <x-coredata://5D617B2C-35BC-43B4-BEC1-40AABA96C558/Cart/p10> ; data: {
    fCost = 60;
    fName = "Butter";
    fQuantity = 1;
})]
```

I am using tableView cell to display the core data and performing the total.

```
var cart = [NSManagedObject]()
let order = cart[indexPath.row]
cell.fNLabel.text = order.valueForKey("fName")! as? String
cell.fCLabel.text = "Rs \(order.valueForKey("fCost") as! NSNumber)"
cell.fQLabel.text = "\(order.valueForKey("fQuantity") as! NSNumber)"
let fQ = order.valueForKey("fQuantity") as! Int
let fC = order.valueForKey("fCost") as! Int
let total = fQ * fC
totalArray.append(total)
grandTotal = totalArray.sum() // sum() is an extension that calculates the sum of integer values
print(grandTotal)
grandTotalLabel.text = "\(grandTotal)"
cell.fTLabel.text = "Rs \(total)"
```

I get the grandTotal, but every time I pull the table the value gets added to the last value.

I also read about using NSFetchRequestController option, but I wasn't able to work with it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're calculating the grand total in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. This is most definitely not the correct place to do so as it will only calculate the grand total for **visible cells**.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cart")
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    print("===\(results)")

    // Calculate the grand total...
    var grandTotal = 0
    for order in results {
        let fQ = order.valueForKey("fQuantity") as! Int
        let fC = order.valueForKey("fCost") as! Int
        grandTotal += fC * fQ
    }
    print("Grand total = \(grandTotal)")

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I'll just make it clear. I want to get the grandTotal which will be sum of all fQuantity * fCost. For ex: fName: Milk, fQuantity: 2, fCost: 30. fName: Butter, fQuantity: 1, fCost = 60. So I want to get (2*30) + (1*60) = 160 -> grandTotal. Your solution is working, but it is giving me fCost (30) of Milk + fCost(60) of Butter = 90. It may be easy, but tried lot of things and I think I am just making it too complicated. Can you update your solution? Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I had overlooked the quantity. I think you are over thinking this, a simple loop would suffice, I will update my answer...

Comment: Ok, I got it working. I removed my comment as it didn't make sense. Your answer works. Just had to add valueForKey. Please accept the edit so that I can accept the answer. I am not mature enough in programming. Thanks for understand.

Comment: AFAIK you only should need `valueForKey:` if the entity is returned from Core Data as a plain `NSManagedObject`. You can make your own custom subclasses and benefit from type safety. But that's a different issue :D